# rsync -avzh /media/sdx/* /media/sdy/ --delete --recursive --links, what is wrong here?

Tags: linux, rsync, robocopy

Rsync is giving me trouble. I use it for a decent backup. I wasn't able to make it match ROBOCOPY.exe.

`rsync -avzh /media/sdx/* /media/sdy/ --delete --recursive --links`

It seems to copy all and everything, yet --delete seems not to be honoured. Please advice me your one liner, since this one, `rsync -aP --delete /media/sdx/* /media/sdy/` does the opposite, deleting too much, I'm baffled.

Comment: Use `rsync -avzh --delete /media/sdx/ /media/sdy/`.  If that doesn't do what you want, please Edit your question and include specific details about what it does and why you believe that's incorrect, and/or not what you want.

Comment: Now it atleast works and doesn't end up maxing out the target drive space. But one last problem still exists, it does copy new files and delete old ones for /media/sdy/<any-dir>, it does copy files to destination from /media/sdx/* but it fails to delete files that are no longer on /media/sdx/  but are on /media/sdy. So it recurses and deletes inside all folders but not the files in /media/sdx/

Comment: Omit the asterisk.  That's why I didn't include it in my suggested command.

Comment: Working. I use rsync -vlaArpEogt --delete-during --temp-dir=/media/sdy /media/sdx/ /media/sdy this is coming close to ROBOCOPY.exe, now I'm after scripting something that makes sure source is read only before omitting since one mistake might take your backup to your current files so be cautious with experimenting on your important files.